# Sql Query Optimization - Remove Not In Operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I am storing employee attendance on a table 'attendance' having the following structure:

```
EmpID, CDate
```

Attendance system insert this table everyday with employee-id of all employees present on that particular day.

I need to find out absent statement of a particular employee. I can do this easily by selecting all distinct date that are not in - dates where the employee is present.

Is there any way I can remove the not in operator on that sql statement. Please help

Here is the sql query for employee with EmpId 01:

```
select distinct CDate 
  from attendance 
  where CDate not in (
      Select CDate from attendance where EmpID='01')
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the NOT IN operator?

Comment: Because it is taking lots of time. I want to decrease it.

Comment: Where is the SQL query that needs to be modified?

Comment: There is a bug in MySQL 5.5 and lower where the IN clause runs unexpectedly slowly when an index is missing. What version of MySQL are you using and what indexes do you have on each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in the NOT IN clause, it is the subquery.

You want something more like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.CDate, if (EmpID=NULL, false,true) as Present
FROM attendance as a1
LEFT JOIN attendance as a2 USING (CDate) 
WHERE a2.EmpID='01'
```

This is a cartesian join which pulls all of the dates, then joins the employee attendance status on that.  Should be significantly faster than your subquery.

---

Updated, with tested code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.CDate, IF (a2.EmpID IS NULL, false,true) as Present
FROM attendance AS a1
LEFT JOIN attendance AS a2 ON (a1.CDate = a2.CDate AND a2.EmpID='01')
```

My bad on the previous answer.  I should have put the subselection into the ON instead of an aggregate.

Comment: It is not working. I am using mySQL. It is listing only those dates where employee is present.

Comment: See updated answer.  I went through, built some data against your 'spec', and tested it.

Comment: It is now listing every working day but 'Present' is always 1. Also this query took almost same time as my previous query(168s vs 174s).

Comment: Perhaps employee 01 is always present? : )  I verified that part works properly.  As far as the slowness, the explains suggests that the cartesian uses two simple selects while yours utilizes a dependent subquery.  Aside from things like caching, mine should be faster in a general perspective.

Comment: While this answer, with some modifications, can be made to work, the problem may simply be a missing index combined with a problem due to a bug in an older version of MySQL that affects the IN clause when the index is missing. Once the index is added or if MySQL is upgdraded, both this query and the original query should be fast (<1s). To OP: what version of MySQL are you using? SELECT @@VERSION.

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.1.32

Comment: @Mark Byers - Sounds like an answer -- and probably the right one.  : )

Comment: Thanks, after adding index, my original query is low lightning fast(0.0268s). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your mechanism to store data for each employee, each day.
Yes, it'll add a lot of rows, but how can you be sure that you'll get all dates from logged data? what if theres nobody at work today? no one will have absense?

If you'd go with:

```
EmpID, CDate, Present
1, {date}, 0|1
```

then you'd have simpler and faster query traded for table size:

```
select CDate from attendance where EmpID = 1 and status = 0;
```